# How do I get a declarative model given a Table object that the model is mapped to in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to obtain all the classes mapped to tables in

```
metadata.sorted_tables
```

I would like to replace these tables, but have to update my model's `__table__` because I am using declarative.

How do I get the mapped model given a table when I am using declarative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy doesn't really support "replacement" of tables in a MetaData object, nor does it support ad-hoc replacement of the table to which a class is mapped.  Individual tables have dependencies on each other as well as on mapped classes, and this system of dependencies can only be constructed additively - there's no support for replacing things.    Only if you totally threw away the MetaData, replaced it with a new one, and called clear_mappers() to remove all mappings, would it be possible to re-map the classes to new tables.  But this would throw away the declarative mappings and there's also no valid use case for doing this.

You'll want to approach your problem differently, such that when you map a class to a table in a particular way, that's the last time you do it for that particular class.